# Calculating Cloud Service Costs

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud-hosting, rackspace-cloud

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

I would like to scale a web application to the Cloud and wanted to know if anyone had any experience calculating costs and could tell me how I would go about that. ***I have NO experience with cloud services at all.***

Currently my production environment consists of **two web servers** and **one database server**.

If the application continues on a linear growth path, eventually, I want to scale to the cloud to avoid any more long term commitments to extra hardware.

I want to be able to create a similar environment I have now as a baseline. Have this as my fixed cost that I will always have.

I also want to calculate my variable costs that will increase with more users or bandwidth.

I don't have a preferred cloud vendor. [Amazon](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/), Rackspace, [Terremark](http://www.terremark.com/services/infrastructure-cloud-services/enterprise-cloud/architecture.aspx) or any other is fine as long as understand how to calculate my fixed and variable costs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calculating cloud-costs is simple on the surface, but complex once you get to the spread-sheets.

The simple part is you need to know 5 things:

- How many servers you need
- What their duty cycle is (probably 24/7 from the sounds of it)
- What kind of IO you do
- How much space you consume
- What kind of bandwidth you need to the internet (or VPC if you're doing that)

Drop that into a spreadsheet with the cloud-provider's costs and you have your per-month costs.

The complex part comes in *identifying* those performance metrics, and working out the exact pricing strategy that works best for you. You already know server-count, and that's probably 90% of your total cloud-costs right there; three always-on servers are going to run you much, much more than you're likely to involve in the form of disk-space, disk-IO, and network throughput.

As for pricing, the cloud providers I know do allow different pricing schemes for rarely-on, sometimes-on, and always-on servers. Generally with a variable up-front cost and reduced hourly costs for the sometimes/always variants that come out to a significantly cheaper per-year cost than the straight-up hourly charge.